# Why can I not extract the data from this basic JSON Example

Tags: json

This is my Java script

```
    function displayCustomerData( p_customername ) 
    {       
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myservlet',
            type: 'GET',
            data: { requesttype : "getcustomerdata" , 
                    customername : p_customername } ,
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function ( data ) 
                    {
                        $("#usernametxt").val( data.customer);
                    },
                    error: function () {
                        alert("Error loading customer data");
                    }
        });
```

on the server side I generate the JSON using the Gson library

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();

  return gson.toJson( customerData );
```

customerData is a simple POJO with two String fields

I have a breakpoint at the Success response from the server

This is what the "data" variable contains in my debugger when I try to get the data from it

```
       data     "{"customer":"cuatomer A","userName":"user A"}"
```

but on my browser console when I do "data.customer"  it tells me that customer is undefined ?
This indicates that there is something wrong with the JSON data but I don't see anything wrong and I can't stare at it any longer... anyone see anything?

I have tried it on Chrome and Firefox incase it was a browser issue,  same problem on both.

Comment: I suspect that data is a string. try var info = jQuery.parseJSON(data); info.customer;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can parse the Data like using JSON.parse(data) and try for data.customer u can get .the result ....

```
 function displayCustomerData( p_customername ) 
   {       
       $.ajax({
           url: 'myservlet',
           type: 'GET',
           data: { requesttype : "getcustomerdata" , 
                   customername : p_customername } ,
                   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                   success: function ( data ) 
                   {
                        var data1 = JSON.parse(data);
                       $("#usernametxt").val( data1.customer);
                   },
                   error: function () {
                       alert("Error loading customer data");
                   }
       });
```

Comment: Thanks guys,  that was it,  The original server side was setup months agon and of course I forget to check the server return type ws set to text/plain.  So parsing it to JSON on client side has worked.  Accepting this answer as I don't think there is anyway to accept a comment ( From Koenyn ) as a correct answer